# Firebase Node.js local testing credential with functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

All of the code below works after `firebase deploy` but throws error when run on local machine:

> Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed
>   to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access 
>   token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND".

How do I change the following config so that it works in local test environment and in Firebase after deploy?

**foo.js** works locally and on firebase
**getUsersFunction** works on firebase but not locally with `firebase emulators:start --only=functions`

I set up two firebase endpoints and run them locally with:
`firebase emulators:start --only=functions`

**index.js**

```js
"use strict";
const fooFunction = require("./foo");
const getUsersFunction = require("./getUsers");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.fooFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   fooFunction.handler(req, res);
});

exports.getUsersFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   getUsersFunction.handler(req, res, admin);
});
```

**foo.js**

```js
exports.handler = function (req, res, database) {
   res.send("foo ran successfully");
};
```

**getUsersFunction.js**

```js
exports.handler = function (ref, res, admin) {
   admin
      .auth()
      .listUsers(1000)
      .then(function (listUsersResult) {
         console.log(listUsersResult);
         res.send("done");
         return null;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log("Error listing users:", error);
      });
};
```

Comment: I don't think auth is emulated by the Firebase emulator suite yet. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the Firebase logs and noticed this:

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and
>   quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these
>   restrictions

The code is fine as is - the error was due to my account restrictions.  I am posting this in the hopes that it can save other developers from wasting the time I did.